An infinite coin-flipping game
Consider a coin-flipping game that costs $1 to play.

If heads, I win $3.
If tails, I win nothing.

I start playing this game with $100, and continue playing infinitely. Am I guaranteed to eventually lose all my money?

I assume by guaranteed, you mean "with probability 1"? There of course exist sequences where you never lose your money

Since there is a probable event that you will lose all your money it means that in the INFINITY case it will happen! This probability is presented in the answers below.

probability to reach any value is strictly positive albeit small to very small for small values  including 0 (starting from 100)

We can model your winnings as an infinite Discrete-Time Markov Chain, where the state is your current dollar amount. From state $i$, you either move to state $i-1$ or to state $i+2$, each with probability 1/2. Starting from state $i$, we can calculate the probability of ever reaching the state $i-1$, i.e. losing a dollar. Call this probability $x$.
The crucial question is whether $x < 1$. A full proof is beyond the scope of this answer, but note that after a  large number of flips $n$, the distribution of the current winnings is approximately a normal distribution with mean $100 + n/2$ and standard deviation $O(\sqrt{n})$. Examining the formula for the tail of a normal distribution, we see that the chance of a normal distribution falling $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ standard deviations below the mean is $e^{-\Omega(n)}$. This series converges, so it gets increasingly rare to ever fall below \$$100$, if it hasn't happened in the first few steps. So $x < 1$.
Now, let's calculate $x$. There is a $1/2$ chance of immediately moving from $i$ to $i-1$, and a $1/2$ chance of moving to $i+2$, from where we will need to descend three times to reach $i-1$. Each of these descents is independent, so $x$ satisfies the equation:
$$x = 1/2 + x^3/2$$
The unique solution in the interval $(0, 1)$ is $x = (\sqrt{5} - 1)/2 = \phi - 1 \approx 0.618$.
To run out of money, we must lose \$$100$. This requires losing a dollar 100 times, independently. This happens with probability $x^{100} \approx 10^{-21}$.
It is very unlikely that you will ever run out of money, as you play the game infinitely.

This seems somewhat incorrect—what if we go to \(i+2\) twice—or more than twice? This doesn't seem to account for that.

@Someone x is the probability of ever reaching i-1, starting from i. If the first flip is heads, the required sequence goes: i -> i+2, then ever reach i+1, then ever reach i, then ever reach i-1. The latter three steps each occur independently with probability x.

Oh, that makes sense.

@kkmmistrustsSE The probability I quoted is the probability of ever reaching $0, in the entire infinite future.

Answer:

 No

Explanation:

 First, let's map the problem to a random walk on the nonnegative numbers, with the initial position $100$ and you move one unit to the left with probability $1/2$ and two units to the right with probability $1/2$. Each walk that eventually lands you at zero involves $k$ right-steps (so $2k$ units to the right) and $100+2k$ left-steps, where $k$ can be any nonnegative integer. For a given $k$, there are several moments in time you could have made the $k$ right-steps. In fact, there are at most $\binom{100+3k}{k}$ moments where you could have made the $k$ right steps (this is an overestimate because we can't take all the left-steps before the right-steps, but we need only an upper bound on the probability that you will reach $0$, so this is okay). Therefore, the number of walks involving $k$ right-steps is at most $\binom{100+3k}{k}$. The probability for such a walk is $2^{-(100+3k)}$ because it involves a total of $100+3k$ steps, so the probability that you will reach $0$ is at most $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{100+3k}{k}2^{-(100+3k)} < 10^{-20}.$$


The question only asks if losing is certain. This answers that.

This is more of a maths questions, but the answer is no, you are not guaranteed to lose all your money. I note that the other answers, at this time, talk about the likelihood of winning, but that is not what you asked.
A guaranteed loss means that there is no path through the game in which you don't lose your money. If we can find just a single path in which you don't lose; then we have proved the point. This is easy to do; in fact there are many. The obvious one is that you always flip heads. It becomes increasingly unlikely as you play more iterations of the game, but however small the chance is, it is never non-zero.
The conditions of the game, such as the starting funds and the amount you win are irrelevant and a distraction. You could start with a single dollar instead of 100 and win 1 cent instead of $3. The answer is the same.

@kkmmistrustsSE - the probability is non-zero, which is all it needs to be

@kkmmistrustsSE It is exactly zero, but that doesn't mean it's impossible. We cannot conclude that things with probability 0 never happen, or that things with probability 1 surely happen - at best we can conclude they almost never or almost surely happen. Even having a 100% chance of losing all your money doesn't actually guarantee that it occurs.

Yes, you are guaranteed to eventually lose all your money if you continue playing infinitely. Although you have a positive expected value, each flip is independent, and there is significant variance. There will be long streaks of tails (losing streaks) that can deplete your balance. Since you have a finite starting balance of $100, you are not infinitely resilient to these streaks of losses.
This is due to the concept of gambler’s ruin in probability theory, which states that with infinite play, the probability of going broke approaches certainty unless you have an infinite bankroll.

This could get quite mathematical.  You might be right, but it's not clear given that the 'ups' are bigger than the 'downs' .  To be convincing the argument would need lots of maths and then would be more suitable for Mathematics Stack Exchange

But this game has a positive expected value—on average, the player gains 50 cents.

@Someone I am not mathematically inclined, but I have a weird suspicion he's correct. Because play is infinite, if we imagine play as an infinite sequence of results (Heads, Tails, Heads, H, T, H, H, H, etc. etc.), the probability that the sequence somewhere contains a finite subsequence with a number of losing flips equal to the bankroll currently available is 1 (P=1). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely

@Oray gambler's ruin does not apply here, as it requires a negative expected value, which this game does not have (this game has a positive one)

@ConnieMnemonic There is a big difference between a sequence containing a specific finite subsequence of flips, and that sequence containing a specific finite subsequence of flips at a specific point. The first one is almost sure, the second depends on other factor. Here, with a positive expected value, there is a probability that you never bankrupt (because bankrupting becomes less and less probable as the sequence goes)

@AloisChristen This seems fair, I am definitely not mathsy. Though I will say, it's not just "1 specific point". If the condition is "Equal to the current bankroll" then there are, in fact, an infinite number of "specific points" that apply. The index doesn't move, but the required sequence length changes each iteration.

For any integer $N$, you will eventually see streaks of $N$ losses in a row; however, in almost all cases, those streaks of $N$ losses will happen so far in the future that you'll have much more than $N$ dollars, and won't be harmed by the streak.
